# Android studio stuck at dialog saying Classes up-to-date check

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am using android studio version 1.1.0 and when I try to save a file then I get a dialog displaying "Classes up-to-date check" and it remains stuck at this.

Could you please suggest what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's the problem here, but I would suggest updating to the newest Android Studio version 1.4.

Version 1.1 is over half a year old.